# How to make gitlab ci runner get its exit code from docker-compose up some_service

Tags: javascript, gitlab, gitlab-ci, cypress, e2e-testing

I'm running e2e tests with cypress on GitLab. here is the command I run to run Cypress tests:

```
docker-compose -f devops/e2e/docker-compose.yml up cypress
```

Cypress service is simply based on `cypress/included:8.4.0` image.

So in my Gitlab job when the tests succeed I get something like this:

```
cypress      |        Spec                                              Tests  Passing  Failing  Pending  Skipped  
cypress      |   ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
cypress      |   │ ✔  login_spec.js                            00:04        1        1        -        -        - │
cypress      |   ├────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
cypress      |   │ ✔  multi_resolution_image_spec.js           00:41        1        1        -        -        - │
cypress      |   ├────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
cypress      |   │ ✔  plain_image_spec.js                      00:40        1        1        -        -        - │
cypress      |   ├────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
cypress      |   │ ✔  signup_spec.js                           00:10        1        1        -        -        - │
cypress      |   └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
cypress      |     ✔  All specs passed!                        01:36        4        4    

cypress exited with code 0
.
.
.
Job succeeded
```

But when the tests fail I get:

```
cypress      |        Spec                                              Tests  Passing  Failing  Pending  Skipped  
cypress      |   ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
cypress      |   │ ✖  annotate_spec.js                         00:02        1        -        1        -        - │
cypress      |   ├────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
cypress      |   │ ✔  login_spec.js                            00:05        1        1        -        -        - │
cypress      |   ├────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
cypress      |   │ ✔  signup_spec.js                           00:13        1        1        -        -        - │
cypress      |   └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
cypress      |     ✖  1 of 3 failed (33%)                      00:21        3        2        1    

cypress exited with code 1
.
.
.
Job succeeded
```

The problem is in case of failure of run tests I'm still getting `Job succeeded` from Gitlab. How can I make Gitlab CI runner get its exit code from cypress service exit code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try use option `--exit-code-from`:

```
docker-compose -f devops/e2e/docker-compose.yml up --exit-code-from cypress
```